# Tabbed navigation goes on new line instead of wrapping tab text on mobile

Tags: html, css

I have tabbed navigation with two tabs. When the screen width is reduced to a small mobile (below 415px), the tabs go onto two different rows instead of wrapping the tab text so that both tabs stay on one line. I'd like some help in wrapping the tab text please. I have tried setting a `max-width`, changing some of the display options, and adding `flex-wrap: wrap;` to no avail.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Clubba/hqud9L46/2/

**HTML**

```
<div class="tab-wrap">
    <input type="radio" id="tab1" name="tabGroup1" class="tab" checked>
        <label for="tab1"><span style="font-family:Montserrat,sans serif;">Tab 1 title</span></label>
    <input type="radio" id="tab2" name="tabGroup1" class="tab">
         <label for="tab2"><span style="font-family:Montserrat,sans serif;">Tab 2 title</span></label>
            
  <div class="tab__content"><br />
Tab 1 content
  </div>
            
  <div class="tab__content"><br />
Tab 2 content
   </div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.tab-wrap {
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s box-shadow ease;
  transition: 0.3s box-shadow ease;
  border-radius: 15px 15px 0 0;
  max-width: 90%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 40px 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02), 0 1px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);

}

.tab {
  display: none;
}
.tab:checked:nth-of-type(1) ~ .tab__content:nth-of-type(1) {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s opacity ease-in, 0.8s -webkit-transform ease;
  transition: 0.5s opacity ease-in, 0.8s -webkit-transform ease;
  transition: 0.5s opacity ease-in, 0.8s transform ease;
  transition: 0.5s opacity ease-in, 0.8s transform ease, 0.8s -webkit-transform ease;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
          transform: translateY(0px);
  text-shadow: 0 0 0;
}
.tab:checked:nth-of-type(2) ~ .tab__content:nth-of-type(2) {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s opacity ease-in, 0.8s -webkit-transform ease;
  transition: 0.5s opacity ease-in, 0.8s -webkit-transform ease;
  transition: 0.5s opacity ease-in, 0.8s transform ease;
  transition: 0.5s opacity ease-in, 0.8s transform ease, 0.8s -webkit-transform ease;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
          transform: translateY(0px);
  text-shadow: 0 0 0;
}

.tab:first-of-type:not(:last-of-type) + label {
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}
.tab:not(:first-of-type):not(:last-of-type) + label {
  border-radius: 0;
}
.tab:last-of-type:not(:first-of-type) + label {
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}
.tab:checked + label {
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #fff inset;
  cursor: default;
}
.tab:checked + label:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #fff inset;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.tab:not(:checked) + label {
  color:#fff;
}

.tab + label {
  box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #eee inset;
  border-radius: 15px 15px 0 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
  -webkit-box-flex: 3;
      -ms-flex-positive: 3;
          flex-grow: 3;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #34404d;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
     -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
          user-select: none;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s background-color ease, 0.3s box-shadow ease;
  transition: 0.3s background-color ease, 0.3s box-shadow ease;
  height: 80px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 90%;
}
.tab + label:hover {
  background-color: #576c82;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #f4f4f4 inset;
}
.tab__content {
  padding: 10px 25px;
  background-color: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-3px);
          transform: translateY(-3px);
  border-radius: 6px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Making `flex-wrap:nowrap;` and adding `min-width: 50%` to `tab` class will make sure your navigation tabs don't go into different rows. But doing this will create problems for your tab contents. And you cannot even move them to different elements because then your checked pseudo element won't work( they works only with descendants or siblings). there can be certainly be better solution which i don't know of but what I realized is you can do following

1. since Your problem boils down to layout  with setting  layout you can use grid instead of flex, since you need 2D layout to prevent navigation tabs from wrapping.
2. you can make use of position and make tab contents position absolutely relative to body or navigation tabs.